# Java version from the dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I want to know the java version of the application from the dockerfile.
The first line of the dockerfile says : FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine .
What is the full version of java here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

the most precise way to find out would be to actually build that dockerfile:

`docker build -t mycontainer .`

then run it with the bash command:

`docker run mycontainer -it bash`

and then check java version:

`java -version`

---

**Option 2**

Alternatively you can just look up on the docker page of the image you are about to use `adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine`, which a simple google search would bring you [to](https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11)

There you would see the version being used is 11.0.11_9, but this might/will change in future releases

Comment: `docker run -rm adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine java -version`